# Printing on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, printing

Hi there can any one help me with this? I am new to iOS development. I am trying to implement a print feature, but I am getting errors in it. I see nothing but `.xib` file with some `labels`. The `textview` is there, I just want to print that view... when i pressed the print button the program is crashing..

Here is my code:

```
- (NSData *)generatePDFDataForPrinting {
    NSMutableData *myPdfData = [NSMutableData data];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(myPdfData, kPDFPageBounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self drawStuffInContext:ctx];  // Method also usable from drawRect:.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    return myPdfData;
}

- (void)drawStuffInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Zapfino" size:48];
    CGRect textRect = CGRectInset(kPDFPageBounds, 36, 36);
    [@"hello world!" drawInRect:textRect withFont:font];
}


- (IBAction)printFromIphone:(id)sender {
    float systemVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

    if (systemVersion>4.1) {

        NSData *myPdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myPdfData]; //check the value inside |myPdfData| and |pdfPath| is the path of your pdf.
        UIPrintInteractionController *controller = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
        if (controller && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:myPdfData]){
            //controller.delegate = delegate; //if necessary else nil
            UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
            printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
            printInfo.jobName = [myPdfData lastPathComponent];
            //printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
            controller.printInfo = printInfo;
            controller.showsPageRange = YES;
            controller.printingItem = myPdfData;

            // We need a completion handler block for printing.
            UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
                if(completed && error){
                    NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u", error.domain, error.code);
                }
            };

            //            [controller presentFromRect:CGRectMake(200, 300, 100, 100) inView:senderView animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
        }else {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't get shared UIPrintInteractionController!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So which error are you getting?

Comment: use of undeclared identifier pdfData.... and can you suggest me any exact tutorial...plz..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its a typo or not but you've commented out your actual pdfData which is why its undeclared.

This line needs to be uncommented because you need `myPdfData`.

```
//NSData *myPdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfData]; //check the value inside |myPdfData| and |pdfPath| is the path of your pdf.
```

You can replace it with this line to use YOUR pdf instead of a file.

```
NSData *myPdfData = [self generatePDFDataForPrinting];
```

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR Reply and again one more error in below method undeclared identifier "rect"              [controller presentFromRect:rect inView:senderView animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

Comment: You need to present it from somewhere. The rect is just the location. You can fill it in with a CGRect of where you'd like it to show up.